# Añadir Event Trigger a array de botonos via script añade siempre el ultimo index

Tags: c#, array, unity3d

Estoy Añadiendo eventos a un array de botones, quiero que mi `button(0)` tenga la función `showint(0)` cuando entra el puntero, pero todos los botones muestran `showint(5)`

Creo que es porque Unity procesa este comando después de ejecutar el script y siempre añade el ultimo index

Este es el código

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    buildTypeButtons[i] = Instantiate(BuildTypeButton, new Vector2(0, posY), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    buildTypeButtons[i].transform.SetParent(panelTypesGO.transform, false);
    EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
    entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerEnter;
    entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => { showBuildTypeName(i); });
    buildTypeButtons[i].GetComponent<EventTrigger>().triggers.Add(entry);
    posY -= 45;
}
```

La función actualmente tiene solo un `Debug.Log(x)` que muestra 5 en todos los botones, alguien conoce la solución? Gracias

Comment: Puedes intentar lo siguiente?: añade `int ID = i;` despues de `entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerEnter;` y cambia el `AddListener` asi:`entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => { showBuildTypeName(ID); });`

Comment: Ha funcionado. Lo he pensado, pero creía que iba a hacer lo mismo,  Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Este problema es muy interesante. En cuanto reabran la pregunta, te daré una respuesta con una explicación de cual era tu problema.

Comment: Parece que es un problema general de c#, Lo explican aquí (ingles) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: No es realmente un problema, es por diseño. Pero si, si no lo sabes puede darte muchos dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 4):

Este problema sucede por la siguiente razón.

Al usar métodos anónimos en C#, se crea lo que se conoce como `Closure`.

> Un closure es, básicamente, un bloque de código que puede ser ejecutado en el futuro,pero que mantiene el ambiente en el que fue creado, es decir, puede utilizar todavía las variables locales del método que lo creó, incluso aunque ese método haya finalizado su ejecución.<sup>1</sup>

Para conseguir esto, lo que se hace es lo que se conoce como `Variables Capturadas`. Sin entrar en mucha profundidad, lo que se hace es guardar una referencia a la variable que se quiere capturar.

Entrando en el caso que nos ocupa. Cuando tu creas el método anónimo `(eventData) => { showBuildTypeName(i); }`, lo que .net hace internamente es almacenar una referencia a la variable `i`. El problema es que esa variable, tras el bucle `for`, acaba obviamente con un resultado de `5`. Con lo que cuando realmente el método anónimo es ejecutado, el valor de `i` siempre sera `5`.

La solución es simplemente crear una referencia interna para cada valor, y de esa manera el `closure` será capaz de capturar la variable con su valor correcto. En tu caso, capturamos el valor de `i` en una nueva variable `ID`, y pasamos esa referencia en el método anónimo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    buildTypeButtons[i] = Instantiate(BuildTypeButton, new Vector2(0, posY), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    buildTypeButtons[i].transform.SetParent(panelTypesGO.transform, false);
    EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
    entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerEnter;
    int ID = i;
    entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => { showBuildTypeName(ID); });
    buildTypeButtons[i].GetComponent<EventTrigger>().triggers.Add(entry);
    posY -= 45;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/428624/579895

(Si alguien quiere profundizar un poco mas en el tema, [aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) hay una explicación de @EricLipper que era parte del equipo de diseño del lenguaje C#, en inglés)